# UNIT тесты на Mocha Chai Sinon (создание затычки , проверка параметров)

Tags: javascript, sinonjs

Если кто разбирается в тестах, подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно реализовать тест двух вещей:

1. Был ли вызван метод `obj.newRing({});` при запуске функции `makeRing`?
2. Совпадает ли параметр `num`, передаваемый в функцию `makeRing(num)` с свойством объекта передаваемого в `obj.newRing({ number: num})`?

Собственно, тестируемая функция:

```
function makeRing(num) {
    currRing = obj.newRing({
        number: num
    });
}
```

Может у кого-то будут какие то соображения, как использовать sinon или что иное в данной ситуации?

Comment: Откуда в функцию попадает `obj`?